# How to enable the menubar in a QUndoView window in Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, window, menubar

I use a QUndoStack and I want to show its content using a QUndoView. I create the view as follows:

```
undoView = new QUndoView(&_undoStack);
undoView->setWindowTitle(tr("Undo Stack"));
undoView->show();
```

The view is created in a separate window (which is what I want), but that window has a disabled menu bar, so I cannot move it at all, or close it. Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: Alt+MouseDown+MouseMove? Alt+F4?

Comment: The window is locked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the issue was that the main window had a window modality of `Qt::WindowModality::ApplicationModal` which blocks all input to any other top-level window. Simply changing the main window to non-modal with [SetWindowModality](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop) fixed this.

```
hide();
setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModality::NonModal);
show();
```

Alternatively change the modality directly in Qt creator if the main window was created from there.